# A question about a class of pro-$\mathcal X$-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, compactness

This question concerns the following lemma of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01298934):

> **Lemma 2.** Let $\mathcal X_1,\ldots,\mathcal X_n$ be classes of finite groups closed with respect to normal subgroups and subdirect
> products and let $\mathcal X$ be the class of groups $H$ having a
> series $$I = H_0\leq H_1\leq\dots\leq H_n = H$$ with
> $H_i/H_{i-l}\in\mathcal X_i$ for each $i$. Then every
> pro-$\mathcal X$-group $G$ has a series $$I = G_0\leq G_1\leq\dots\leq G_n = G$$ of
> closed characteristic subgroups such that
> $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is a pro-$\mathcal X_i$-group for each $i$.

The author wrote after this lemma:

> The *proof* of this by induction on $n$ is straightforward and may be
> omitted.

I do not know how this induction works. Could someone explain it for me, please?

Comment: Well, once you establish the case of $n=2$, it remains to show that under the hypotheses you give, the class $\mathcal X$ is closed under normal subgroups and subdirect products (and that a closed characteristic subgroup of a closed characteristic subgroup is a closed characteristic subgroup, but that's clear). Then it seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: @tomasz My problem is to prove exactly the case $n=2$, how can I  extract the existence of closed characteristic subgroups from the hypothesis.